# return value "constrained" by function type in Scala

Tags: function, scala, compiler-construction, types

It seems empowering that one can effectively make assertions about legal return *values* of implementing methods just based on the type of the abstract function/method.
I intuitively feel (most of) the compiler behaviour below makes sense but I would appreciate a clear explanation of why I should be able to assert that

```
def f[T](t: T): T
```

can only be the identity function (except that class E compiles too). I can appreciate that *we know nothing about T* as it is not bounded, but there are gaps in that explanation. 
The compiler reporting "found scala.Int(42) required Int" is not getting me closer to the light.

```
trait A{ def f[T](t: T): T }
// compiles
class B extends A{ override def f[Int](t: Int): Int = t }
// does not compile
class C extends A{ override def f[Int](t: Int): Int = t + 1 }
// does not compile
class D extends A{ override def f[Int](t: Int): Int = 42 }
// compiles
class E extends A{ override def f[Int](t: Int): Int = 42.asInstanceOf[Int] }
// compiles
class F extends A{ override def f[Int](t: Int): Int = identity(t) }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your examples is that the `Int` in your examples is **not** the normal 32-bit integer type (which is `scala.Int`); instead, you have a type parameter that happens to be named `Int`. That's confusing you: you think your `Int` is `scala.Int`, but it isn't, it's a type parameter with a confusing name.

So, for example this:

```
class C extends A{ override def f[Int](t: Int): Int = t + 1 }
```

Does not mean you are defining a method that takes a `scala.Int`; you're defining a method with a type parameter that has the name `Int`. You could give it any other name, for example `X`, then it would be exactly the same:

```
class C extends A{ override def f[X](t: X): X = t + 1 }
```

It doesn't compile because there are no constraints on the type parameter, so the compiler doesn't know that the type has a `+` method.

Comment: Or you could just drop the `[Int]` from `B` through `F`.

Comment: That is exactly what I was thought I was doing, thank you! It explains the compiler's complaint too. 
How does the cast of 42 to my Int work?

Comment: The cast compiles, but when you'd try to run it and you use something else than `scala.Int` for the type, you'd get a `ClassCastException`. For example `f(0)` would work, but `f("hello")` would throw an exception because you would be trying to cast `42` to the type `String`.

Comment: Rex, how would the B look, for example, if I drop the [Int]? 
    class B extends A{ override def f(t: Int): Int = t }
gives - method *f overrides nothing*

Comment: @involuntary - That's because you have no implementation to override.  You're just providing the implementation that the trait specifies.

Comment: but it also says B must be abstract as it does not define f[T](t: T): T
even with override removed. I used 'override' just a s a sanity check, and if I understand correctly that should be OK (like @Override in Java on implementations of interface methods)

Comment: is it a general rule that one can make assertions re the return values based on the type of the function or is this (identity) a special case? It seems like a pretty powerful tool if it can be used in other places. I can see that this may be a bit of a theoretical discussion - do you know of any papers on this, if it is indeed a useful technique more generally than only this case with identity?

Comment: @involuntary - My mistake, the `[T]` is on the function.  In that case, you don't satisfy the trait unless you supply a function that works with arbitrary `T`.  If that's not what you want, you should put the `T` on the trait; then you can extend `A[Int]`.

Answer (score 1):

Jesper has the correct answer with the main question: `[Int]` isn't filling in a type of `Int` for `T`, it's creating a new generic type parameter confusingly named `Int`.

But I also have an addendum:

You are being a little too trusting that the user won't do something sneaky, even if it's valid at runtime.

```
def f[T](t: T): T = (t match {
  case i: Int => -i
  case s: String => s.reverse
  case b: Boolean => !b
  case o: Option[_] => None
  case s: Seq[_] => throw new Exception("Ack")
  case _ => t
}).asInstanceOf[T]
```

Not exactly the identity function any more, is it?  If you forbid matches and `asInstanceOf` and exceptions and so on, then it's got to be identity.

Comment: so, if we do ignore those cases for a minute, what is the most succinct way to describe how you know 
    
    `f[T](t: T): T`
 
_ must be identity_?

Comment: @involuntary - At runtime, you do not know what the compile-time type `T` is.  Therefore, you cannot produce one de novo; you must used the instance that's passed in.  Because the type is unknown, you can only use operations valid on all types.  There are no operations defined on all types that return the same type.  So the only possible choice is identity.

Comment: "Because the type is unknown, you can only use operations valid on all types. There are no operations defined on all types that return the same type." - I think that is the key, thanks!

Comment: @involuntary - Keep in mind that uninitialized vars are part of "and so on": `class Defaulting[U]{ var u: U = _ }` allows you to `def f[T](t: T) = { (new Defaulting[T]).u }`

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody's answered the other part of the question yet:

In general, this property is called *parametricity*, and the guarantees you get from it are called *free theorems*.  This only holds, by the way, if you ignore typecase (and unmarked side effects), so a huge part of Scala doesn't count.

Comment: ... that sounds like what I was looking for. I guess in Scala (with its support for 'impure' style too) once could make use of parametricity if one is in control of the code base. 
Thanks, I'll see what I can find to read re parametricity.